# Manrill UNSUB merge tag with with dynamic url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mandrill

I'm wondering if there's a way to pass a dynamic url to the UNSUB merge tag.

I'm using rails with the [MandrillMailer](https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer) gem and my mailer script looks something like this

```
mandrill_mail template: @email.template,
subject: @email.subject,
to: @user.email,
inline_css: true,
vars:{
  'SETTINGS_LINK_TO' => @settings_url,
  'UNSUB_LINK_TO' => @unsub_url #http://siteurl.com/unsubscribe
}
```

I can confirm that `SETTINGS_LINK_TO`, and `UNSUB_LINK_TO` are showing up in merge tags in the email just fine... however, when I try to add `UNSUB_LINK_TO` to my UNSUB merge tag (see below), it isn't parsed.

```
<a href="*|UNSUB:UNSUB_LINK_TO|*"> Unsubscribe </a>
```

If I hard code the unsubscribe address it works fine.
Is there any way to pass a dynamic address in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, no, because merge tags can't be nested. They get rendered once, so you can't embed a merge tag inside the unsub merge tag. You'd need to have a separate API call for each recipient and pass their version of the unsub URL, or take advantage of the fact that Mandrill provides an id and email address as query params when generating the full unsub link. In general, the unsub merge tag was designed to be really simple for users who can't set up, or don't have, a distinct unsub process on their website/for their database. So if you've got something more specific to your environment or users, it may be better to go ahead and just provide your own unsubscribe link and bypass the Mandrill one (it's not required to use it if you've got your own that removes recipients who want to opt out of bulk or promotional emails).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So if I do my own unsub process, I should just go ahead and generate a link to my app that will grab their email address and then make a separate call to Mandrill to add the user to the blacklist? Also, if a user goes to their settings page, checks a box that says they want to receive emails, should/can I add that user to the Mandrill whitelist? Or should I just remove them from the blacklist. (sorry for compounding my question)

Comment: No worries - it's up to you if you want to add them to the blacklist. That's really designed if you don't have anything built in to your system to prevent those people from getting emails. If you have an unsub process, and you accurately block those recipients from getting the emails they've opted out of, no need to sync that with Mandrill's blacklist unless you really want to maintain that.